# C program to calculate the distance between a point and a line

Tags: c, line, distance, point

I have a point `(x1, y1)` and a line `y = m.x + q`. And, my task was to find the shortest distance between the given point and the line.

Below is my C code for the same.

Could someone help me with my code, because it gives me a bit of errors *(Wrong answers)*

```
#include "punto_retta.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double x1,y1,m,q,distance;

int main () {

    printf ("Enter the coefficient 'm' of the line: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &m);
    printf ("Enter the coefficient 'q' of the line: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &q);
    printf ("Enter the value of x1: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &x1);
    printf ("Enter the value of y1: \n");
    scanf ("%lf", &y1);

    distance = (fabs (y1 - (m * x1 - q))) / (sqrt (1 + m * m));

    printf ("The distance is %.3f \n", distance);
}
```

Comment: You need to post the errors, in snippets and the more important pieces. A bit of a high level overview of your problem also helps the SO community solve your problem as well.

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output, and observed output.

Comment: *What* errors?  Is it failing to compile?  Is it crashing?  Is it giving you unexpected output? Are you making sure that the math library is getting linked in properly?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you were making mistake while calculating the formula for the distance between the point `(x1, y1)` and the line `y = m.x + q`.

**Replace:**

```
distance = (fabs (y1 - (m * x1 - q))) / (sqrt (1 + m * m));
```

**With:**

```
distance = (fabs (y1 - m * x1 - q)) / (sqrt (1 + m * m));
```

**EDIT:** See the reason you kept on getting *Compilation Error* is because `y1` has already been declared in `math.h` Header File. And, I guess if i am not wrong, you must be using C++ compiler to compile your code.

```
... Rest of the upper code of math.h header file
_CRTIMP double __cdecl j0 (double);
_CRTIMP double __cdecl j1 (double);
_CRTIMP double __cdecl jn (int, double);
_CRTIMP double __cdecl y0 (double);
_CRTIMP double __cdecl y1 (double);     // y1 is declared here
_CRTIMP double __cdecl yn (int, double);

_CRTIMP double __cdecl chgsign (double);

... Rest Code
```

**DO:** Change the name of the variable `y1` to some-thing else in your C program file.

Comment: This is the errors: "redefinition of 'y1' as different kind of symbol
double x1,y1,m,q,distance;" ; "warning: format specifies type 'double *' but the argument has type 'double (*)(double)'" ; "invalid operands to binary expression ('double (*)(double)' and 'double')
distance = (fabs (y1 - m * x1 - q)) / (sqrt (1 + m * m)); "

Comment: I have solved! The problem was the name of the variable y1: I replaced the name with y and it worked! ... But I didn't understand why...

Comment: @stark The error is not in the `punto_retta.h`. See my edited answer.